# ¿Es "hacer la trece catorce" una expresión del español neutral?

Tags: expresiones, coloquialismos, español-neutral

Aunque a veces se oye la versión incorrecta "hacer la *tres* catorce", la expresión "hacerle la trece catorce" a alguien quiere decir "hacerle una jugarreta, engaño o mala pasada".

Acabo de aprender que el origen de la expresión viene de los talleres mecánicos.

[image]

Los calibres de las llaves fijas son: 6-7, 8-9, 10-11, 12-13, 14-15, 16-17, etc. El calibre "13-14" no existe, pero en los talleres mecánicos a veces se burlaban de los aprendices pidiéndoles buscar la llave "13-14" (y claro, los pobres no podían encontrarla).

Yo la verdad es que siempre pensé que esta expresión tenía un origen distinto (más "local"), y me quedé sorprendido al aprender esto. Me pregunto si esto significa que esa expresión es entendida y usada en todos los países de habla hispana o al menos en otros aparte de España.

Comment: Interesante el origen de la expresión. No sé por qué siempre pensé que venía del fútbol y que era la "tres catorce" pero lo que dices tiene mucho más sentido. He trabajado en algún taller y, efectivamente, el número de llave no coordina.

Comment: Me encanta la forma de la pregunta (¿Es una expresión del español neutral?).  (No conocía esta frase, pero mi opinión no cuenta, porque mi vocabulario es un poco limitado.)  Pero Diego, te falta algo importante en la pregunta, no nos has dicho cómo descubriste la etimología maravillosa.  (Gracias por incluir la imagen.  Si resuelves el defecto, propondré esta pregunta para Las Mejores Preguntas del Sitio.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al menos en lo que conozco de español en Colombia, y lo que he leído y oído en varios medios de Hispanoamérica, es la primera vez que leo la frase. No la tenía referenciada y al hacer la tarea por la forma "fácil" (buscar la frase en google, en sitios alojados en Colombia) no aparece tampoco. Sin embargo, en yahoo answers aparece [esta pregunta](https://ar.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080227065554AA1YysH) y un usuario que dice ser de España menciona no haberla oído. No creo ser la autoridad sobre el tema, pero no la calificaría como parte del español neutral

Comment: Concuerdo, esa expresión nunca la le oído en Colombia.

Answer (score 0):

Quién viva en España sabe que significa la expresión "**hacer la trece catorce**".

Es una frase que se en España, al menos donde yo resido y es normal que en Colombia no la conozca y aún menos lo que quiere decir.

Cuando se usa la expresión "**hacer la trece catorce**", es para indicar que alguien te ha hecho una "jugarreta", una trastada, es decir, un engaño, una mala jugada o faena.

Comment: De hecho no contesta a la pregunta sobre si es del español neutral o no.